# Apache2 subtext can't acces 000-default

Tags: web-server, server, services, apache-httpd

I have been using `Apache2` and `webmin` with my Raspberry Pi. After a restart and reinstallations Apache won't start.

```
> sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
apache2: Syntax error on line 268 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
failed!
```

The file 000-default is there and unopenable permisions to root-root.
My `apache2.conf` file looks like this (bottom half).

```
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel debug

# Include module configuration:
Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on and which to use for name based vhosts
Include ports.conf

#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive (see below).
# If you are behind a reverse proxy, you might want to change %h into %{X-Forwarded-For}i
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see the comments above for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
Include conf.d/

# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include sites-enabled/
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory /var/www>
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
ServerName IMASERVER
</VirtualHost>
```

Does anyone know what is the cause of this?

Comment: What is the output of ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-enabled?

Comment: And could you mark which line is 268 in your apache2.conf ?

Comment: > ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pi root 26 Oct  8 03:52 000-default -> ../sites-available/default
@alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the files in the `sites-enabled/` directory are actually symlinks to their counterparts in the `sites-available/` directory.

For some reason it looks as if the file that `000-default` is linked to is not there any more. You should be able to tell if I'm right by executing the following, which I think will give you some errors about `dangling symlinks`:

```
sudo a2ensite default
```

That command essentially renews the symlinks between the two directories.
So, the default site configuration is broken, but it's not actually needed. You can safely delete the contents of `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`:

```
sudo rm /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
```

The `apache2.conf` file already contains a site configuration at the bottom, so it should work without any sites enabled, but add any new sites into the `sites-available/` directory and enable them with the `a2ensite`.

Comment: You were right about the error.    > sudo a2ensite default
ERROR: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default is a dangling symlink!
ERROR: Site default does not exist!
   I'll test out your solution in the morning.(I'm on my iPhone now)

Comment: @enrique2334: Glad I could help :)